# Merge [parse-error] and [parsererror]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Both [parse-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-error) and [parsererror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsererror) mean the exact same thing.  Merging them would make sense.

It would be most logical to keep [parse-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-error) as it has more questions and is more descriptive.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, it's [tag:parse-error] which should stay: More questions, an (even appropriate) wiki, better tag-name imho...

Comment: I feel like [parse-error](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/parse-error/info) may be merged with [syntax-error](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/syntax-error/info), judging by their wikis.